# El método me pide que añada un return

Tags: java, eclipse

tengo un problema y es que tengo un método el cual eclipse me obliga a añadir un return sí o sí a pesar de tenerlo ya metido en el código. (He revisado los if y sus else pero en principio está todo bien metido, es decir si no hay un true, hay un false. En principio está todo bien "cerrado")

```
    public boolean crearProducto(Producto producto) {
    if (this.sill1 == null || this.sill2 == null || this.puer1 == null || this.puer2 == null || this.vent1 == null || this.vent2 == null) {
        if (producto.getTipo().equals("Silla")) {
            if ((producto.getId() != sill1.getId()) && (producto.getId() != sill2.getId())) {
                if (this.sill1 == null) {
                    this.sill1 = producto;
                    return true;
                } else if (this.sill2 == null) {
                    this.sill2 = producto;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            
        } else if (producto.getTipo().equals("Puerta")) {
            if ((producto.getId() != puer1.getId()) && (producto.getId() != puer2.getId())) {
                if (this.puer1 == null) {
                    this.puer1 = producto;
                    return true;
                } else if (this.puer2 == null) {
                    this.puer2 = producto;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            
        } else if(producto.getTipo().equals("Ventana")) {
            if ((producto.getId() != vent1.getId()) && (producto.getId() != vent2.getId())) {
                if (this.vent1 == null) {
                    this.vent1 = producto;
                    return true;
                } else if (this.vent2 == null) {
                    this.vent2 = producto;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }   
        }   
        
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return false;    //Aquí es donde me obliga a poner el return
}
```

Este es el mensaje: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por la ayuda, y si no me explicado bien, decidme porfavor

Comment: Como dice FranyXD, todo if/else debe tener un return, en tu caso, los if/else-if/else principales no tienen return, por lo que te pide que lo añadas para esos casos, ya que puede cumplirse alguno de esas condiciones, pero no tiene porqué los del if/else hijo que tenga (no he revisado a fondo tu caso, pero es lo general). Por lo que, o añades un return en esos sitios, o creas una variable boolean con un valor por defecto y devuelves ese valor, cambiándolo como hace Pablo Lozano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ese método es bastante complejo (si hicieras un grafo con todos los posibles caminos verías que tiene muchas ramas), con lo que es un buen candidato a:

- simplificarlo: estás comprobando si alguno de los atributos es null, pero luego vuelves a comprobarlo para cada tipo. Eso es redundante.
- usar un único return: crea una variable con el valor a devolver y devuélvelo al final.

Por ejemplo:

```java
public boolean crearProducto(Producto producto) {
    boolean resultado=false;
    
    if (producto.getTipo().equals("Silla")) {
        if (this.sill1 == null) {
            this.sill1 = producto;
            resultado = true;
        } else if (this.sill2 == null) {
            this.sill2 = producto;
            resultado = true;
        }
    } else if (producto.getTipo().equals("Puerta")) {
        if (this.puer1 == null) {
            this.puer1 = producto;
            resultado = true;
        } else if (this.puer2 == null) {
            this.puer2 = producto;
            resultado = true;
        }
        
    } else if(producto.getTipo().equals("Ventana")) {
        if (this.vent1 == null) {
            this.vent1 = producto;
            resultado = true;
        } else if (this.vent2 == null) {
            this.vent2 = producto;
            resultado = true;
        }
    }   
    return resultado;
}
```

El motivo por el que eclipse te dice que falta un return es fácil de ver: ¿qué pasa si el producto es de tipo Silla pero sill1 y sill2 no son nulos?

Comment: Voy a hacer el grafo y te comento

Comment: he actualizado la respuesta, el código se puede simplificar aún más quitando errores (NPE) que iba a aparecer en ejecución

Answer (score 1):

El return te lo devuelve por si todo lo que has puesto no se cumpliera nada pues no funciona por decirlo de manera mas coloquial